# Storybook with Tailwind throwing unknown word error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm trying to use Tailwind, React (CRA), and Storybook but my current setup is throwing this error. I'm using TypeScript on top of Create React App.

```
src/index.css Unknown word

> 1 | var api = require("!../node_modules/@storybook/addon-postcss/node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
    | ^
  2 |             var content = require("!!../node_modules/@storybook/addon-postcss/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].use[1]!../node_modules/@storybook/addon-postcss/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].use[2]!./index.css");
```

.storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          // When you have splitted your css over multiple files
          // and use @import('./other-styles.css')
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          // When using postCSS 8
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react",
  "core": {
    "builder": "webpack5"
  }
}
```

.storybook/preview.js

```
import "../src/index.css"

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

relative devDependencies, I am also using ESLint but I don't think that'd cause any issues? If so I will edit to add the ESLint dependencies I have.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  }
```